# Javascript - How to wait for image to load? Cant get img.load to work?

Tags: javascript, canvas

In my javascript i draw onto a canvas, after that i whant the canvas to be converted to a png and shown in a div with the folowing code:

```
var dataURL = document.getElementById('myCanvas').toDataURL("image/png");
var imgObj = new Image();
imgObj.src = dataURL;
imgObj.onload = function() {document.getElementById('myImg').appendChild(imgObj); };
```

When i call this directly after drawing the canvas i get a completly blank image in "myImg" but if i call exactly the same code with the click on a link it gets drawn properly:

```
<a id="viewImgLnk" href="javascript:void()" onclick=" return convertCanvasToImage();">View Image</a>

<script>
    function convertCanvasToImage(){
        var dataURL = document.getElementById('myCanvas').toDataURL("image/png");
        var imgObj = new Image();
        imgObj.src = dataURL;
        imgObj.onload = function() {document.getElementById('myImg').appendChild(imgObj); };
    }
</script>
```

How can i get the image loaded directly without the link?

Comment: put your script end of the body tag.

Comment: where your code is located when you call it "directly"? are you sure you have the canvas drawn at this moment?

Comment: @allergic If i call _alert(document.getElementById('myCanvas').toDataURL("image/png"));_ i get a huge string, i guess that means my canvas is loaded, or is there a way to wait for the canvas to be loaded aswell?

Comment: try setTimeout(). but you didnt answer where your code is located?

Comment: Ah sorry, its located in a external file included on the page

Comment: Thank you verry much for the help! I got it working with setTimeout, i will post an answer with the solution =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the code working with the help of allergic!

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var dataURL = document.getElementById('myCanvas').toDataURL("image/png");
    var imgObj = new Image();
    imgObj.src = dataURL;
    imgObj.onload = function() {document.getElementById('myImg').appendChild(imgObj); };
}, 300);
```